# Generating combinations of data based on probability of previous data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, combinations, naivebayes

I have a data set(Example) of the following type:

Food Type: Chinese, Indian, Thai, Mexican

Ingredient 1: Salt, Chinese Salt

Ingredient 2: Chilli, Red Chilli, Thai Chilli, Green Chilli

Ingredient 3: Turmeric, Cardamom,

Ingredient 4: Chicken, Beef, Fish, Tofu

I have some combinations of data made by hand and I classified them in different food types based on ingredients and recipes. I need to generate more data based on the most probable combinations. One way I have done it so far is to generate all combinations of all ingredients and then classify them into food types based on previous learning. But this approach will not be practical as the data is large. Each category of ingredient can have more than 30-40 values. Moreover, Ingredients are not just 4, they are much more in real data set.  I am looking for better ways to generate and classify the data than my already proposed approach. I have applied NB classifier to classify the data.  Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not get any replies for over 4 four months, I thought of posting my solution which might help someone else.

The technique I used was to get top five most important features from each of the attribute types(food types in my example). Then I made combinations of all those features. For the rest of the features, I chose a value randomly. This generated new data which was manageable in size.

If you need any clarifications, please feel free to ask.